# iOS - Get first non empty string element from array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have array:

```
let array = ["", "Therapeutic Dentistry","Surgical Dentistry","Orthopedic Dentistry","Orthodontics","Genaral Medical Questions","Children Therapeutic Dentistry","Children Surgical Dentistry"]
```

And i want get firs one, it's empty, how i can get this element from array?

Comment: So you want to get the first non-empty element from the array?

Answer (score 8):

Arrays have a `first` property which gives you the first element if it exists.

```
if let firstElement = array.first {
    print(firstElement)
}
```

If you want the first element that is not an empty string then you can use the `first(where:)`

```
if let firstElement = arr.first(where: { $0 != "" }) {
    print(firstElement)
}
```

**Edit:**

Question title was "iOS How get first element from array Swift" in the beginning which is why the answer has two parts.

Comment: but if i have second element, it's only check first element

Comment: I mean, if my first element if empty, but second is avalible how i can check it?

Comment: @Andrew, that's what the second block of code is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

`let firstElement = array.first ?? DefaultValue`

It means

`let firstElement = array.first != nil ? array.first! : DefaultValue`

DefaultValue is anything you defined.

Comment: An empty string is not the same as an unset optional string

Answer (score 0):

Filter the array by removing "" values and get the first element.

```
array = array.filter({ $0 != "" })


    if let first = array.first{
        print(first)
    }
```